# How to access saved bitmap as a file on android?

Tags: android, android-file

I am saving a Bitmap (bitmap) to a file as follows:

```
String fileName = "image.jpg"; 
try { 
  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes); 
  FileOutputStream fo = openFileOutput(fileName,
       Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
  fo.write(bytes.toByteArray()); 
  fo.close(); 
} catch (Exception e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

How to access the saved image as a file? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you specifically need a `File` object for it? Because you can use `openFileInput()` to get an `InputStream`. If you do indeed need a `File`, to what end, exactly? That is, is it just for your app's internal use? Or do you need to pass it externally?

Comment: Yes, I need a File object for it. It's for my app's internal use.

Comment: Well, if you absolutely have to have a `File` object, the directory that `openFileOutput()` saves to can be obtained with `getFilesDir()`, so your `File` would be `new File(getFilesDir(), fileName)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String fileName = "image.jpg"; 
try { 
  String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(); //path where the file will be stored.

  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes); 
  File file = new File(path,fileName); // the File to save , append 
  FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
  fo.write(bytes.toByteArray()); 
  fo.close(); 
} catch (Exception e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

don't forget to add Storage Permission and get the permission on runtime as well.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```